# show Figure as plot instead of browser

Tags: python, plotly

I'm new in plot\figure and trying to show my output in local plot instead of showing in browser.

This is my code and my output shows in my browser.
How can I show it in plot window?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(value = [3739 3770, 4761, 42125, 4957, 5028, 6048, 80985, 1474.2, 1558.6, 998.1, 38642.1],

                   variable = ['1', '2', '3', '4',  '1', '2', '3', '4',  '1', '2', '3', '4'],
                   group = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A',  'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',  'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']))
       
fig = px.line_polar(df, r = 'value', theta = 'variable', line_close = True, color = 'group')
fig.update_traces(fill = 'toself')

fig.show()
```

Comment: How do you run that code? Do you run this in a jupyter notebook? You shouldn't use jupyter in that case. Just run the code with a python interpreter on the shell.

Comment: @buhtz I'm run it from pycharm and at the end the code will be an exe file.

Comment: See the documentation https://plotly.com/python/renderers/

Comment: @EricLavault I have already seen this documentation, still cannot show it as a plot. Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: Eg. `fig.show(renderer="svg")`. What did you try ? Do you need the plot to be interactive ? What do you mean exactly by "_show it as a plot_" ?

Comment: @EricLavault with Figure

Comment: my output from fig.show(renderer="svg") is text @EricLavault